# Difference between Chome Array.sort and FF's

Tags: javascript

This simple:

```
list.sort(function(a, b){return a.priority < b.priority;});
```

where list items are like `{priority: 2, foo: "bar"}`

Doesn't behave the same on the 2 main browsers, what am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/8NCXr/1/

[image]

Comment: you're supposed to return a numeric not a boolean in your `sort()` function: 1, 0 or -1.

Comment: ah right thanks, working with: return b.priority - a.priority

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> return a.priority < b.priority;
> ```

That's not a valid compare function. Returning `0` (or `false`, in your case) would mean that the two items are considered equal - which they are not always. To be consistent, the compare function would need to fulfill the equation

```
comp(a, b) == -1 * comp(b, a)
// or, if not only the values -1, 0 and 1 are allowed:
comp(a, b) * comp(b, a) <= 0
```

If that requirement is broken, the sort will behave undefined.

Citing the [ES5.1 spec on `sort`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.11):

> If `comparefn` is […] not a consistent comparison function for the elements of this array, the behaviour of sort is implementation-defined.
>
> A function `comparefn` is a consistent comparison function for a set of values `S` if all of the requirements below are met for all values `a`, `b`, and `c` (possibly the same value) in the set `S`: The notation `a <CF b` means `comparefn(a,b) < 0`; `a =CF b` means `comparefn(a,b) = 0` (of either sign); and `a >CF b` means `comparefn(a,b) > 0`.
>
> Calling `comparefn(a,b)` always returns the same value `v` when given a specific pair of values `a` and `b` as its two arguments. Furthermore, `Type(v)` is Number, and `v` is not `NaN`. Note that this implies that exactly one of `a <CF b`, `a =CF b`, and `a >CF b` will be true for a given pair of `a` and `b`.
>
> - Calling `comparefn(a,b)` does not modify the this object.
> - `a =CF a` (reflexivity)
> - If `a =CF b`, then `b =CF a` (symmetry)
> - If `a =CF b` and `b =CF c`, then `a =CF c` (transitivity of `=CF`)
> - If `a <CF b` and `b <CF c`, then `a <CF c` (transitivity of `<CF`)
> - If `a >CF b` and `b >CF c`, then `a >CF c` (transitivity of `>CF`)
>
> NOTE: The above conditions are necessary and sufficient to ensure that `comparefn` divides the set `S` into equivalence classes and that these equivalence classes are totally ordered.

To compare numbers (reverse) in JavaScript, simply

```
return b.priority - a.priority;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to return a numeric not a boolean in your sort() function: 1, 0 or -1. These numbers represent the direction the comparing element should travel (up, stay or down). A boolean doesn't give you this control, so most likely it's up to how the browser wants to handle it (therefore making it vary between browsers).

Check out the docs on [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Assuming an ascending sort:

```
list.sort(function(a, b){
  return a.priority > b.priority ? 1
       : a.priority < b.priority ? -1
       : 0;
});

// yields priorities of: [-8,-7,-3,0,1,3,12,29,30,200,1992]
```

Comment: Returning booleans is actually fine, as they will be converted to `0` or `1`. However, that doesn't form a valid ordering, and different sorting algorithms will lead to different incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

If u like it to work in booth browsers u should change two small things.

First how u parse ur int.

```
list.forEach(function(data){data.priority = parseInt(data.priority,10);});
```

Then the sort so it returns a direction and not true/false.

```
list.sort(function(a, b){return b.priority - a.priority;});
```

This is ur fiddle but [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/8NCXr/3/) with the fix.

Comment: This will give the descending order.